# Django REST Framework - Only first query parameter showing in request.get_params

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I would like to filter a queryset in a view using multiple query parameters, but "request.query_params" is only able to get the first query parameter in my query string.

Here is my URLConf:

```
urlpatterns = [
   ...
   re_path(r'^descsearch/$', views.DescriptionSearchView.as_view(), name='descsearch'),
]
```

Here is the top of my view where I'm attempting to get two query parameters from the query string ("description" and "descSearchMethod"):

```
class DescriptionSearchView(generics.ListAPIView):
serializer_class = DrawingSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    print("request.query_params: " + str(self.request.query_params))
    description = self.request.query_params.get('description')
    print("description: " + description)
    descSearchMethod = self.request.query_params.get('descSearchMethod')
    print("descSearchMethod: " + descSearchMethod)
    ...
```

When I make this GET request using curl:

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/descsearch/?description=O-RING&descSearchMethod=and
```

The print statements in the Django console show that only the first query parameter "description" is in QueryDict.

```
request.query_params: <QueryDict: {'description': ['O-RING']}>
description: O-RING
Internal Server Error: /api/descsearch/
...
```

If I switch the order so that "descSearchMethod" is the first query parameter, only it shows.

Why is only the first query parameter showing in QueryDict?

Comment: Can you print `self.request.GET`?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!  I just needed to add quotes around the URL in my curl command, like this:

```
curl -X GET 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/descsearch/?description=O-RING&descSearchMethod=and'
```

I'm issuing the curl command in a Git Bash on Windows.